# edeliver -- scp is unable to find a build

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, edeliver

Until recently, "edeliver" has worked well, but now it throws this error:

I have this error when deploying

```
[skipped]
==> Tarball updated!
==> Release successfully built!
    You can run it in one of the following ways:
      Interactive: _build/prod/rel/my_website123/bin/my_website123 console
      Foreground: _build/prod/rel/my_website123/bin/my_website123 foreground
      Daemon: _build/prod/rel/my_website123/bin/my_website123 start
-----> Copying release 0.1.5 to local release store
-----> Copying my_website123.tar.gz to release store
scp: /home/my_user123/my_website123/builds/rel/my_website123/releases/0.1.5/my_website123.tar.gz: No such file or directory

RELEASE BUILD OF my_website123 WAS SUCCESSFUL!

[skipped]

DEPLOYING RELEASE OF my_website123 APP TO PRODUCTION HOSTS

-----> Authorizing hosts
ls: cannot access '.deliver/releases/my_website123_*.*.tar.gz': No such file or directory
No *(s) found in local release store.
You can build one with the ./edeliver build * task.
```

Previously, about a month or 2 weeks, ago it worked well.

Elixir 1.4.0

And also, what does "tput: terminal attributes: No such device or address" mean in here:

```
   tput: terminal attributes: No such device or address

    tput: terminal attributes: No such device or address
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with Elixir (and OTP at all.)

This is SSH who is the beast. One of SSH commands, being executed by `edeliver`, is trying to send some message to a terminal. If there isn’t one open, this happens.

Try to `ssh` to the destination manually, you’ll likely see what’s wrong. Eliminate the root cause of something being tried to put into `STDERR`/`STDOUT`, and your deploys will turn back to normal.

Comment: nothing wrong when I log in via ssh. However, "tput: terminal attributes: No such device or address" isn't a big issue. The issue is that I'm unable to deploy.

Comment: These two issues are [IMHO] connected. Have you tried to `scp` manually?

Comment: Not yet. but scp fails because of "No such file or directory" because bloody edeliver or distillery doesn't copy my release to the release folder anymore. I've done that manually.